# Python Concatenate/Append - I'm not quite getting this?

Tags: python, pandas, append, concatenation

I have several files I've created (4 files, file 1 = a list of 1-100, file 2 = a list of 101-200...etc), all of which are just a list of ID's. I am trying to create a single file, with all the ID's in a single column (IDs are unique so a single column works).

I can't quite get it though - I keep getting close but not quite what I need.

I think I'm missing something related to assigning indexes or something? any insights are greatly appreciated!

```
import pandas as pd
URL1 = "C:\\PATH\\" + fileName + "1" + ".csv"
URL2 = "C:\\PATH\\" + fileName + "2" + ".csv"
URL3 = "C:\\PATH\\" + fileName + "3" + ".csv"
URL4 = "C:\\PATH\\" + fileName + "4" + ".csv"

data1 = pd.read_csv(URL1)
data2 = pd.read_csv(URL2)
data3 = pd.read_csv(URL3)
data4 = pd.read_csv(URL4)

data_concat = pd.concat([data1, data2, data3, data4])

data_append = data1.append(data2)
data_append2 = data_append.append(data3)
data_append3 = data_append2.append(data4)
```

when I:

```
print(data_append3)
# or 
print(data_concat)
```

i get:

```
      1  101  201    301
0   2.0  NaN  NaN    NaN
1   3.0  NaN  NaN    NaN
2   4.0  NaN  NaN    NaN
3   5.0  NaN  NaN    NaN
4   6.0  NaN  NaN    NaN
..  ...  ...  ...    ...
94  NaN  NaN  NaN  396.0
95  NaN  NaN  NaN  397.0
96  NaN  NaN  NaN  398.0
97  NaN  NaN  NaN  399.0
98  NaN  NaN  NaN  400.0

[396 rows x 4 columns]
```

Edit:

Print(data1)

```
1    101
    0   2.0    NaN
    1   3.0    NaN
    2   4.0    NaN
    3   5.0    NaN
    4   6.0    NaN
    ..  ...    ...
    94  NaN  196.0
    95  NaN  197.0
    96  NaN  198.0
    97  NaN  199.0
    98  NaN  200.0
```

print(data2)

```
      1  101    201
0   2.0  NaN    NaN
1   3.0  NaN    NaN
2   4.0  NaN    NaN
3   5.0  NaN    NaN
4   6.0  NaN    NaN
..  ...  ...    ...
94  NaN  NaN  296.0
95  NaN  NaN  297.0
96  NaN  NaN  298.0
97  NaN  NaN  299.0
98  NaN  NaN  300.0
```

I tried adding this and it worked! thank you :)

```
data1 = pd.read_csv(URL1,header =None)
data2 = pd.read_csv(URL2,header=None)
data3 = pd.read_csv(URL3,header=None)
data4 = pd.read_csv(URL4,header=None)

print(data_append3)

      0
0     1
1     2
2     3
3     4
4     5
..  ...
95  396
96  397
97  398
98  399
99  400

[400 rows x 1 columns]
```

Comment: Show the outputs for `print(data1)`, `print(data2)`, etc.

Comment: The first value of each file is being read as a column header. Try adding the header argument to each read_csv() call like so: `data1 = pd.read_csv(URL1, header=0)`

Comment: I've added the outputs for these! Each "append" is just adding a each file as a column.

Comment: @NitinLabhishetty this worked!

data1 = pd.read_csv(URL1,header =None)
data2 = pd.read_csv(URL2,header=None)
data3 = pd.read_csv(URL3,header=None)
data4 = pd.read_csv(URL4,header=None)

Comment: `append` doesn't return a new list; it updates the list in-place.